# git, how to push to multiple remote repos with different user.email?

Tags: git

I have a project named `mall`

I have two remotes and two accounts.

I want to use `git push` to push to these two remotes with a different account, Like this:

`user.email='a@g.com'`   push to  `git@github.com:a/mall.git`

`user.email='b@g.com'`   push to  `git@github.com:b/mall.git`

Comment: This should be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-on-github

Comment: `user.email` only affects your commits. Are you sure this is what you are asking?

Comment: @xuhdev yes. because I have two accounts , and I want the github to calculate the contributors for two accounts. You know , the contributors need the correct `user.email`

Comment: @novaline In this case, the two repos are not synchronized. Are you sure you wanna do this?

Answer (score 0):

The email is set at the commit, not at the push. A different email means a different sha, which means you'd better have 2 different repos: A and B.

Here is what you can do:

Code, commit and push in repo A.
Create a script to do the following :

- copy paste your project
- execute git filter-branch to replace a@g.com into b@g.com
- push to B

Everytime you push on A, run the script, or automate it using a hook.

Comment: Please do not suggest using `filter-branch` without explaining the consequences of doing so. OP’s workflow already appears to be broken based on their requirement but using `filter-branch` will only make it worse.